# How to reload external javascript on page change using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have couple pages within mobile version of the website which use google location services. I'm using changePage Ajax function to navigate through website pages. On first page load location services works properly , if I go to different page and go back it doesn't.

When I add `rel="external"` it works, but the problem is it reloads entire page which is not a big deal for desktop application, but doesn't look nice on mobile.

I tried to add `reloadPage = true` to changePage but it doesn't make any difference

Is there any way to reload just location services without reloading entire page?

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ></script>

$("#btn-loc").click(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#btn-loc", { reloadPage: true }, { transition: "slide" });
    });
```

Comment: Are you using the page load event or pageChange/pageShow to call the google services?  The page load event only fires for the initial page, not any others that are loaded via AJAX

Comment: I have reference at the top of the page, so page load event. Do you know how I can loaded on pageChange event?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `reloadPage : true` you have to reference the location of the external page, not the ID of that pseudo-page element:

```
$("#btn-loc").click(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("/btn-loc.html", {
        reloadPage : true,
        transition : "slide"
    });
});
```

Also notice how I passed in the options object, there should just be one with all the properties you want to set in the single object.

> **reloadPage** (*boolean*, default: false)
>
> Forces a reload of a page, even if it is already in the DOM of the page container.
>
> - Used only when the 'to' argument of changePage() is a URL.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html*

## Update

To add a script to the DOM via JS you can use Google's Analytics code:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = '/path/to/my-file.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the way you suggested. It works the same way as my code. It's not loading external file <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ></script>

Comment: If you are including that file in the head of the document then it will be ignored upon AJAX navigation. Place the include within the `data-role="page"` element or add the script to the DOM programatically.

Comment: It's within data-role="page". Could you show me how to add script to the DOM programatically?